# Is it possible to have an "offline" react app?

Tags: reactjs

I wondered:

is it possible to initially load a react interface, and, when offline, hold data in the browser until the browser comes online again?

So, for instance: I'm on a train and go to the site, write and 'save' text locally and when I'm home again, sync this text to the server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe you can do that by tapping into the browser LocalStorage. Essentially, you keep track of connection to the server, if no connection, keep the data in the browser local storage, and once it's up send it to the backend

You can search more with keywords like "React" "LocalStorage" "save\retrieve data" and more to find online.

Here's one example i found [online](https://spacejelly.dev/posts/how-to-save-state-to-localstorage-persist-on-refresh-with-react-js/)

```
useEffect(() => {   window.localStorage.setItem('MY_APP_STATE', JSON.stringify(showBanner)); }, [showBanner]);
```

Here's a [page](https://www.kindacode.com/article/react-ways-to-store-data-locally-in-the-browser/) with examples of different approaches

I personally use [localForage](https://www.npmjs.com/package/localforage) for convenience:

Here's some nice sample code to get you started. Gotten it from [here](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/js-localforage)

```
    import localForage from 'localforage';
const foo = 'hello world';

// Setting...
localStorage.setItem('myuniquekey', foo);
localForage.setItem('myuniquekey', foo);

// Getting...
localStorage.getItem('myuniquekey');   //=> 'hello world'
localForage.getItem('myuniquekey');    //=> 'hello world'
```